# Cannot pinpoint a UIView memory leak in my UITableViewController viewDidLoad method

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

I've been cleaning up my code and so far so good, and I only have one leak left to take care of; the one I can't find!

Instruments points me to the following code in my UITableViewController:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.parentView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 50)];
    self.parentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    self.parentView.opaque = NO;

    self.mainButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [self.mainButton setTitleColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0.16f green:0.16f blue:0.16f alpha:1.0] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self.mainButton setTitleShadowColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    self.mainButton.titleLabel.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0.0, 1.0);
    [self.mainButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"grayButton.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    self.mainButton.titleLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:14];
    self.mainButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 4, 102, 35);
    self.mainButton.center = CGPointMake(160, 25);
    [self.mainButton setTitle:@"Control" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self.mainButton addTarget:self action:@selector(controlIt) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    [self.parentView addSubview:self.mainButton];
    self.tableView.tableHeaderView = self.parentView;
}
```

`parentView` is released in `dealloc`. I've also released `mainButton` but I'm not sure it's needed in this case.

I'm wondering if it has something to do with this line:

```
self.tableView.tableHeaderView = self.parentView;
```

The odd thing is, that the leak points to an address which I think is the main view of the view controller because it has over 75 entries of memory retains/release/autorelease in it's history.

Really stuck on this one, would appreciate some guidance.

Comment: The line you pointed out IS the problem. By setting your parentView as another property, it still will have a retain count of +1 and that leaks. Set that property to nil in -dealloc.

Comment: So how does that work in terms of memory management? By setting parentView to nil in `dealloc` the retain count is deducted by 1 or is it completely wiped?

Comment: You can go ahead answer the question so I can accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line you pointed out IS the problem. By setting your parentView as another property, it still will have a retain count of +1 and that leaks. Set that property to nil in -dealloc.

Answer (score 1):

If parentView is a retained property, then this leaks:

`self.parentView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 50)];`

Your release in dealloc would balance the property assignment but nothing balances the alloc.
Try Product->Analyze and see what it says.